# How to map backspace key in inputrc

Tags: bash, inputrc

I want to set the backspace key to the usual backward-delete-char in vi-command mode. In bash, `ctrl-v + <backspace>` outputs `^?`.

I've tried the following in my `~/.inputrc` file but find that `<backspace>` has not been remapped.

```bash
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
control-?: backward-delete-char
"^?": backward-delete-char
backspace: backward-delete-char
```

Comment: In emacs mode, bash (via readline) reads terminal settings and binds the terminal's erase character to `backward-delete-char`. I guess it does something similar in vi mode. I don't know how to work around this, it might take some source code reading (of both readline and bash, as a workaround might exist only via bash commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key name is `Rubout`. You probably want to bind it to `vi-delete` (`x` in normal mode) or `vi-rubout` (`X` in normal mode):

```
set keymap vi-command
Rubout: vi-delete
```